# Dealing with infinite loops in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I've recently joined an iPad project. In looking through the code base I've come across some unusual things, one of which is this (I've meta-coded this):

```
while (something.isAlwaysTrue) {
    // Wait for something to happen. i.e. Get data from an internet connection.
    // Respond to something.
}
```

I didn't notice any problems with this until I started memory profiling the app and found that these loops are memory leaking massively. The reason being that because they never end, any `autorelease` instances created inside them are never freed because the method never ends and the autorelease pools never get a chance to free up.

After talking it through with the developers who wrote the code I came up with the following technique:

```
-(void) queueTask {
    // Using GCD or perform with delay, call the process method.
}

-(void) process {

    // Wait and/or do stuff. 

    [self queueTask];
}
```

The basic idea is that by using a method to queuing through GCD or the runloop, it gives the autorelease pool a chance to execute and clean up `autorelease` instances. This appears to work just fine.

My question is - is this the best way to go about dealing with these loops? or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two points;

**Minimizing Heap Growth**

anyway, here's how minimize memory growth:

```
while (something.isAlwaysTrue) {
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
  // Wait for something to happen. i.e. Get data from an internet connection.
  // Respond to something.
  [pool release], pool = 0;
}
```

or if you prefer the bleating (sic) edge:

```
while (something.isAlwaysTrue) {
  @autoreleasepool{
    // Wait for something to happen. i.e. Get data from an internet connection.
    // Respond to something.
  }
}
```

autorelease pools just operate like thread local stacks. when you push a pool, autoreleased objects are added to the top pool in the current thread. when you pop the pool, the pool sends a `release` message for each autorelease.

using GCD as a substitute for an autorelease pool is odd; similar to using an `NSArray` of single character `NSString`s where you should simply use a single `NSString`.

**Mutithreaded Program Flow**

the infinite loop is a very suspicious program. it suggest you may be trying to reinvent run loops. the main run loop is of course common. a secondary thread 1) with a run loop 2) that never ends is unusual.

you should reconsider how the program flows. typically, you act on events, rather than holding your breath, polling until they complete. you may be trying to break from that situation in the program you proposed -- but i don't have enough detail.

Comment: Exactly right. I would suggest @autoreleasepool, then if you ever switch to ARC that method will be ready.

Comment: Unfortunately this endless loop is something the developers have placed in quite a number of places. I like the idea of embedding an autorelease pool. I had not thoughts of that. Especially in loops which are waiting for data from servers. The architecture is maintaining a connection and waiting for the server to decide to send something to it. Could be seconds, could be minutes. THe GCD thing was the first thing I thought of given what I had read about autoreleasing. I agree that infinite loops smell bad. That's why I started looking at these sections of code.

Comment: @drekka +1 for looking into it. the approach that is currently in use can easily sap the system. I don't know the requirements or execution well enough, but (assuming you must poll) it may help to reimplement all these infinite loops and instead funnel them all into something like one `NSOperationQueue`. Ideally (in the majority of cases), that queue would be serial so that the polling would not starve the resources. Still, it's unusual that the request will never end, that they don't break from the loop, don't cancel, (cont)

Comment: (cont) and the dependent implementation is unable to influence the request's flow (I may be assuming too much). The system would also benefit by delayed retries for requests which timed out. That implementation would at least marshall the requests since the problem (waiting indefinitely) does not benefit from parallelization. It's also quite possible that the serial poll would execute and feel *faster* since there is less competition for resources overall. The serial poll is suspicious, but the approach would improve most cases that fit the requirements.